# intent not working when second activity contained image button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

so here's what i need : first page -> linked to second page (with several image button) -> linked to different third page.

now i have tried the "first page -> linked to second page" stage.

activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="This is first activity" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Move to second activity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.acer.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Button buttoon;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Intent move= new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
    buttoon=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttoon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(move);
        }
    });

  }
}
```

ActivityTwo.java :

```
package com.example.acer.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
    }
}
```

it is actually working when the second page DID NOT contained any image button.

activity_two.xml (WORKING) :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="Second activity"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

button without any image is also WORKING :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second activity" />
```

but when you added image, it's just not working.

using button with background image (NOT WORKING):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second activity"
    android:background="@drawable/image"/>
```

using image button (NOT WORKING):

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second activity"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

and i really need for the second page to have image button. please enlighten me where am i wrong or is there another trick.

ps : when i say not working i mean it build smoothly but it just forced closed in the android phone when the intent is called. so no logcat entries.

Comment: Recheck the logs, seems like you're reaching the limits of your heap

Comment: does it cotain `I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 7.473MB for 2536932-byte allocation`?

Comment: are you using the same id for button,textview and Imagebutton?

Comment: Are you sure that `drawable/image` exists at the place you think it should be? Didn't you misspelled it by mistake?

Comment: If there's a crash, there's a stack trace. Show it.

Comment: @howdoidothis yeah turn out my image was to big in size. i figured it out because the answers here. but i swear there's nothing on my logcat

Comment: @Ritesh no. i just replace them, so each try only contain one element, so no same id.

Comment: You probably didn't see anything in logcat because of "filters" - but glad the answer helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is probably too large and you are getting an OOME (Out Of Memory Error)

[Force close after first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176180/force-close-after-first-run)

Decrease the size of your image. The "default" heap size is usually 24MB (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14869) which is really easy to burn past.

You probably need to increase the heap size on the device for your app:

[How to increase heap size of an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)

EDIT:

I should add that you should make every effort to reduce image sizes before automatically increases the heap size. Otherwise, you will run out of heap later and then have a huge mess cleaning up all the image files that are too large.

Answer (score 0):

Resize your image, try 100dp x 100dp and put it in your drawable folder. Increasing heap size is not recommendable.